# How can i insert integer in char array in c++ using shifting?

Tags: c++, arrays, hex, ascii

I am really new to c++ so sorry if this question is bad or not understandable.

I have an integer, for example, `int a;` its values can be between 1 and 3500 (this value I get from a file). I also have an array of chars, `unsigned char packet[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];`. My goal is to place this integer value in this array between indexes packet[10] and packet[17] So in the end takes 8 bytes.

If the value for a is 1 i would like my packet array to be:

```
packet[10] = 30, packet[11] = 30, packet[12] = 30, packet[13] = 30, packet[14] = 30, packet[15] = 30, packet[16] = 30, packet[17] = 31
```

Comment: Did you have any ideas so far?

Comment: How do you convert the integer value to the array?

Comment: I found something like this, but this coverts it to hex and I don't really understand this so well
`unsigned char bytes[4];
int n = 175;

bytes[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
bytes[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytes[2] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF; 
bytes[3] = n & 0xFF;`

Comment: The code in you comment does not convert it it hex. You should read about what the `&` operator does and what `0xFF` represents and is used for (hint: `0xFF` has all 8 bits of a byte set to one)

Comment: thank you for your comment, I will investigate this on a deeper level

Comment: Be careful about types. You don’t have “an array of chars”. You have an array of `unsigned char`s. `char` is a distance type, and an array of unsigned chars is not an array of chars. `char` will be the same size as `unsigned char`, but it’s up to the implementation whether it is signed or unsigned.

Comment: The code you commented does what you want: an `int` is almost always ([https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types]) 32 bits, and a `char` (unsigned or not) is _always_ 8 bit. So you can 'split' your `int` into 4 `char`s with the appropriate shifts.

Comment: @melk "*a `char` (unsigned or not) is always 8 bit*' - actually no. The standard defines a `char` only as being *1 byte* (`sizeof(char) == 1`), but a byte is not *always* defined as being 8 bits. It is on most modern systems, but technically it is implementation-defined and platform-dependent. `<climits>` defines [`CHAR_BIT`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) to specify how many bits are actually in a byte. It is *usually* 8, but not *always*.  There are systems out there that have a byte size other than 8 bits.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Damn, that just made me feel like there is nothing in this world you can trust :D I always assumed 1 byte = 8 bits, guess i was wrong... thanks for the correction ;)

Comment: So i decided to do this like this: 
`char tids[MAX_TID_LEN];
snprintf(tids, 8, "%08d", i);`

So next what should I do is convert every element of tids and into hex an place it in the `unsigned char packet[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];`

For this i tried `snprintf(buff, 8, "0x%02X", tids[i]);` but it does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look into binary representation and binary math to really understand what bit-wise operations do to values.

Note that 3500 easily fits into a 16 bits value, 3500 is less than 2^16.
If you want to use types with guaranteed sizes, you have to use `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` and similar.

Such operations require a careful approach in case of C++, if you want a potable code. An int may have different size and even different order of bytes (endianness), but operators of bit-wise shift >> and << are agnostic to endianness. Operator << always shift toward higher digits, >> always shifts to less significant ones.

Note, that in C++ results of all bit-wise operations are promoted to be of size of `unsigned int` or larger type if required. Shift operations with signed values are not defined.

In naive but safe variant of required algorithm  we have to do those steps.

(Decide in which order we write bytes down into the buffer. Let assume we do that  from less significant to more significant.)

1. Determine first byte to write value to to, pointed by `p`
2. Determine size of written value in bytes, a `pend` pointer  defines a byte after the written value.
3. "Cut" first byte out of the original value by using AND operation (&) and mask consisting of all 1's and assign it to the location pointed by `p`.
4. Remove written byte from value by shift to the right (>>).
5. Increment `p`.
6. If (p != pend) go to 3.

(optional) we can save `p` or `pend` for further purposes, e.g. for sequenced writes.

In C-styled  (but already C++) variant this would look like:

```
unsigned char * pack_int(unsigned char *p, unsigned value)
{
    unsigned char *pend = p + sizeof(value);
    while(p != pend)
    {
        // ~ is a bit-wise not, ~0 produces an int with all bits set
        *p = value & ((unsigned char)~0); 
        value >>= CHAR_BIT;
        p++;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Use of `((unsigned char)~0)` instead of `0xFF` literal is simply a protection from bytes that aren't 8 bit. Compiler would convert it into correct literal value.

C++ allows to make this implementation to be type-agnostic. E.g. one that still requires sequenced iterators to address output location:

```
template <class InIt, class T>
InIt pack(InIt p, T value)
{
    using target_t = std::make_unsigned_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>>;
    using src_t = std::make_unsigned_t<T>;
    
    InIt pend = p + sizeof(T);
    src_t val = static_cast<src_t> (value); // if T is signed, it would fit anyway.
    
    while(p != pend)
    {
         *p = (val & (target_t)~0);
        val >>= CHAR_BIT;
        p++;
    }
    
    return pend;
}
```

In C++17 one can use

```
InIt pend = p; 
std::advance(pend, sizeof(T));
```

A better implementation in C++ would generate conversion sequence statically, during compilation, instead of using a loop, by application of recursive templates.

This is a fully functional program that uses both :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <climits>
#include <type_traits>

// C-styled function
// packs value into buffer, returns pointer to the byte after its end.
unsigned char * pack_int(unsigned char *p, unsigned value)
{
    unsigned char *pend = p + sizeof(value);
    while(p != pend)
    {
        // ~ is a bit-wise not, ~0 produces an int with all bits set
        *p = value & ((unsigned char)~0); 
        value >>= CHAR_BIT;
        p++;
    }
    return p;
}

// a type-agnostic template
template <class InIt, class T>
InIt pack(InIt p, T value)
{
    using target_t = std::make_unsigned_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>>;
    using src_t = std::make_unsigned_t<T>;
    
    InIt pend = p + sizeof(T);
    src_t val = static_cast<src_t> (value); // if T is signed, it would fit anyway.
    
    while(p != pend)
    {
         *p = (val & (target_t)~0);
        val >>= CHAR_BIT;
        p++;
    }
    
    return pend;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::array<unsigned char, 16> buffer = {};
    
    auto  ptr = pack_int(&(buffer[0]), 0xA4B3C2D1);
    
    ptr = pack(ptr, (long long)0xA4B3C2D1);   
    pack(ptr, 0xA4B3C2D1);   

    std::cout << std::hex;
    for( auto c : buffer)
        std::cout << +c << ", ";

    std::cout << "{end}\n";
}
```

Output of this would be

`d1, c2, b3, a4, d1, c2, b3, a4, 0, 0, 0, 0, d1, c2, b3, a4, {end}`

The sequence `d1, c2, b3, a4`, repeated twice, is obviously a reversed representation for hex value `0xA4B3C2D1`. On little-endian  system that matches representation of `unsigned int` in memory. For 3500 (hex 0xDAC) it would be `ac, d, 0, 0`.

In communications a "network order" is accepted as a standard, also known as "big-endian", where the most significant byte comes first, which would require a slight alteration to the algorithm above.